# Quotes output in jQuery .load vs getJSON result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, getjson

I have the following jQuery that sets the content of each (empty) DIV (with unique id's that start with alpha characters) that has a class = 'editable'. I'm using an MVC4 api controller with a GET method to return a string of HTML.

For some reason the loadStuff function below is outputting quotes that can be seen in the web page before and after the returned content. This happens on every DIV and is definitely not returned in the api controller method returning a string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.editable').each(function () {
          var curId = this.id.replace('content', '');
          loadStuff(curId, this.id);
     })
});

function loadStuff(curId, targetId) {
     $('#' + targetId).load('api/briefingItem/' + curId);
}
```

However when I replace the loadStuff function with the code below and use .appendTo the quotes don't appear.

```
function loadStuff(curId, targetId) {
     $.getJSON("api/briefingItem/" + curId,
          function (data) {
               $(data).appendTo('#' + targetId);
          })          
}
```

This seems overkill for returning a simple string and documentation suggests. Can anyone explain this unusual behaviour?

API Controller

```
// GET api/BriefingItem/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    string newVal = string.Empty;

    switch (id)
    {
        case 12:
            newVal = @"<p>this is some example text that you can edit inside the <strong>tinymce editor</strong>.</p><p>nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. nunc interdum viverra sodales. morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. duis elementum congue ultrices. cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. in hac habitasse platea dictumst. pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.</p>";
            break;
        case 13:
            newVal = @"<p>look up $(content).load() jquery method and the callback function.</p>";
            break;
        default:
            newVal =  @"<h3>click to enter content.</h3>";
            break;
    }

    return newVal;
}
```

Comment: What does you `$.getJSON` response look like? I'd expect sth like `$(data.snippet).appendTo('#el')` as the data returned should always be an object.

Comment: Well the value of data in $(data) is html as follows: <p>this is some example text that you can edit inside the <strong>tinymce editor</strong>.</p><p>nam nisi elit, cursus... etc.  It's valid xhtml form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual response from the Web API is a string which is enclosed in double quotes.

The difference between the `$.getJSON()` and `.load()` methods is that the `$.getJSON` method assumes that the response is a JSON encoded string => it strips the double quotes wheres .load assumes HTML and doesn't do any processing on the result.

So you could have your Web API controller action return a `text/html` instead of `application/json` encoded request:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    string newVal = string.Empty;

    switch (id)
    {
        case 12:
            newVal = @"<p>this is some example text that you can edit inside the <strong>tinymce editor</strong>.</p><p>nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. nunc interdum viverra sodales. morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. duis elementum congue ultrices. cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. in hac habitasse platea dictumst. pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.</p>";
            break;
        case 13:
            newVal = @"<p>look up $(content).load() jquery method and the callback function.</p>";
            break;
        default:
            newVal =  @"<h3>click to enter content.</h3>";
            break;
    }

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(newVal, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Now you could use the `.load()` method but not the `$.getJSON` method.

Comment: Thank you very much Darin that code you posted works a treat :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could post the Controller API signature.

The behavior of load and getJSON are different, i am assuming the controller returns a JsonResult and hence sending quotes, load blindly posts whatever is returned by the controller as HTML and hence the quotes

Comment: Have added API controller code. As mentioned in original post it just returns a string.  I'm just loading some html into a template on the client basically.